# Distributed transaction the same connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, distributed-transactions

Hi I noticed that if I use two edmx , and each one has it's own connection string, but they point to the same database, and server, user and password is the same, then distributed transaction is created. Is it any way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to  tell `EF` about the `single Database connection`. You can do it simply by `openning` the connection yourself after creating the `context`.

**Like this :**

```
  using (var ctx = new YourEntities())
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

        //your other code
    }
```

Comment: how this should work ? Do I need to cast both ctx1 and ctx2 to IObjectContextAdapter ? Do I need to implement this infterface ?